# How can I use WSDLToJava of Apache CXF in my Ant buildfile to create Java code from a WSDL?

Tags: web-services, ant, jboss, cxf, wsdl2java

How can I use WSDLToJava of Apache CXF in my Ant buildfile to create Java code from a WSDL?

Answer (score 1):

There are several examples on the official [Apache documentation page](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html), e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="cxf wsdl2java" basedir=".">   
   <property name="cxf.home" location ="/usr/myapps/cxf-2.5.1"/>

   <path id="cxf.classpath">
      <fileset dir="${cxf.home}/lib">
         <include name="*.jar"/>
      </fileset>
   </path>

   <target name="cxfWSDLToJava">
      <java classname="org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava" fork="true">
         <arg value="-client"/>
         <arg value="-d"/>
         <arg value="src"/>
         <arg value="MyWSDL.wsdl"/>
         <classpath>
            <path refid="cxf.classpath"/>
         </classpath>
      </java>
   </target>
</project>
```

Please update your question to be more specific if this does not answer your question.

You will of course need to download CXF and set `cxf.home` to the relevant location, and set `MyWSDL.wsdl` to the path of your WSDL file.